# PDO pagination with LIKE

Tags: php, sql, pdo

The following PHP SQL code shows error
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in /home/customer/xxxx/fetch_data.php on line 28
I was trying to display products information from the table `filter`
There are two    `$statement->execute();`, one is to count total search results and another one is to display products for the current page.
I new to PDO method and not an expert in overall coding.

The  `$filter_query = $stmt . 'LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'';` is causing issues.
With that and related functions, the code works and displays data. But if I enable it, the error shows up.

```
    $limit = '5';
$page = 1;
if($_POST['page'] > 1)
{
  $start = (($_POST['page'] - 1) * $limit);
  $page = $_POST['page'];
}
else
{
  $start = 0;
}
$search = "%samsung%";
    
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM filter WHERE product_name LIKE :needle");
    $stmt->bindParam(':needle', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    ##
    
    ##
    
    
    $filter_query = $stmt . 'LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'';
    
    $statement->execute();
    $total_data = $stmt->rowCount();
    
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($filter_query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $total_filter_data = $stmt->rowCount();
    
    $output = '
     <h3> '.$total_data.' results found </h3>  
    and display each product
```

I tried the following code as suggested by `Your Common Sense` and the pagination and total search result count is working fine, but no products are getting displayed.

```
    $limit = '5';
    $page = 1;
    if($_POST['page'] > 1)
    {
      $start = (($_POST['page'] - 1) * $limit);
      $page = $_POST['page'];
    }
    else
    {
      $start = 0;
    }
    $name=str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['query']);
    $search = "%$name%";
    $base_sql = "SELECT %s FROM filter WHERE product_name LIKE ?";
    ##
    
    ##
    ####
    $count_sql = sprintf($base_sql, "count(*)");
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($count_sql);
    $stmt->execute([$search]);
    $total_data = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    ####
    $data_sql = $count_sql = sprintf($base_sql, "*")." LIMIT ?,?";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($data_sql);
    $stmt->execute([$search, $start, $limit]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    ##
    
    $output = '
   <h3> '.$total_data.' results found </h3>  ';
if($total_data > 0)
{
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
            and display each product
```

Using the following line makes the code show some data, but the pagination is not working.

```
$data_sql = sprintf($base_sql, "*");
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($data_sql);
    $stmt->execute([$search]);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: don't concatenate the limit offset on the statement object, do it in the query statement (just right after the like clause) in which case it should have its own placeholder

Comment: @Kevin, if you have time, kindly show an example. I tried $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM filter WHERE product_name LIKE :needle LIMIT '.$start.', '.$limit.'"); and it shows zero products

Comment: Have you checked whether executing the query throws an error in the database?

Comment: @Nico Haase, No, actually this code was working fine before I tried to add the "prepared statement" feature. also it counts the pages correctly.

Comment: If it worked before, and does no longer after changing the query, why not check for error messages? Also, which of these lines is the one mentioned in the error message?

Comment: @NicoHaase, error log shows no error and the page itself is also showing no errors.

Comment: Do you still use the given code? It does not check for PDO errors anywhere - that's something you should use `$stmt->errorInfo()` for, directly after the line throwing the error message you've posted initially

Comment: @NicoHaase, I tried the $stmt->errorInfo(); and no errors are showing. But please note that currently no errors are showing anywhere. Just the products are not displaying as it should. I have updated the question, slightly modifying few lines makes the results to show, but then pagination stops working.

Comment: @NicoHaase FYI, PDO can throw exceptions, hence there is no need to litter your code with $stmt->errorInfo();

Comment: Good to know that - but for debugging purposes and with a more or less unknown configuration of the whole system, it can help to use this explicitly and temporary

Comment: @NicoHaase what do you mean, "unknown configuration"? How it can be "unknown" for the person who writes the code? And there is absolutely no use for whatever "debugging purposes". It's a concept from the early PHP days some 20 years ago that has absolutely no use anymore.

Comment: @NicoHaase, here is the website link http://shijilt8.sg-host.com/search/ , try typing "samsung"

Comment: Who knows the rest of the code? Maybe there is some configuration to catch all exceptions and just throw them away?

Comment: @NicoHaase, should I post the whole script somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a not a trivial task as we need to run the same query twice but with minor differences. The first query will use `count(*)` SQL function to get the total number of records matching the search criteria. The second query will select actual fields with LIMIT clause to get the data for the single page.

```
$base_sql = "SELECT %s FROM filter WHERE product_name LIKE ?";

$count_sql = sprintf($base_sql, "count(*)");
$stmt = $connect->prepare($count_sql);
$stmt->execute([$search]);
$total = $stmt->fetchColumn();

$data_sql = $count_sql = sprintf($base_sql, "*")." LIMIT ?,?";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($data_sql);
$stmt->execute([$search, $start, $limit]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

**Important:** In order for this code to work, make sure you are [connecting to mysql properly](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). the proper connection will let a LIMIT clause to accept placeholders and also will warn you in case of any problems.

Comment: I tried it and the results section shows "100 results found". There is only 7 entries in the database and only pagination section is showing this data. Product section not showing anything

Comment: changing  "count(*)");" shows correct page numbers, but still no products are showing

Comment: regarding the product section your start and limit variables should have sensible values

Comment: yes, start and limit has values. edited my question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Why $data_sql = $count_sql = sprintf($base_sql, "*")." LIMIT ?,?"; ... is $count_sql necessary ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, after adding try catch in the database conenctions ection, it shows following error "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0','5'' at "

Comment: @YourCommonSense, but if there is no proper connection, how is it calculating total results and page numbers according to search string ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I still cant understand why it shows error "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0','5'' at line 1 in..."

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I am sorry, you code works now. I believed teh exisitng PDO connection might be enough and avoided your "make sure you are connecting to mysql properly. ". Now it works after using the exact method shown in that link. Thank You.